# Circle foreign key reference insert MySQL and transaction rollback

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm using MySQL and InnoDB and I've run into some problem recently.

This is the statement I'm trying to run (I've removed some personal details):

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
INSERT INTO zdb_user (U_DateStart, U_Main_Adres_ID)
VALUES ('2012-04-08', 0);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

SET @newUID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO zdb_adres (A_User_ID, A_Zipcode, A_Number)
VALUES (@newUID, '1234AB', 12);

UPDATE zdb_user SET U_Main_Adres_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE User_ID = @newUID;

COMMIT;
```

The problem is that I'm using a 'circle' foreign key reference. I bypassed that now by disabling the key checks.

`zdb_adres.A_User_ID` requires a valid `User_ID`. And `zdb_user.U_Main_Adres_ID` requires a valid `Adres_ID`, but I don't have either one. Now this all works 'okay' as long as the record in zdb_user can actually be created. But there are several constraints on it that could cause it to not be created.

I thought that on an error the transaction would halt, but after running a simple test I discovered this isn't true at all. Therefore I went googling and I found several solutions like:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND BEGIN ROLLBACK; CALL ERROR_ROLLBACK_OCCURRED; END;
```

Too bad it doesn't work, I'm receiving a syntax error when I add it after the `START TRANSACTION;`:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND BEGIN ROLLBACK' at line 1
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Why don't save yourself a world of hurt and get rid of the circular reference? An address_User table would get rid of all this pain, huge violation of the KISS principle this.

Comment: How would that be simpler? It'd first of all not ensure data validity, and it'd introduce the possibility of many to many, which is not what this is. This is a one to many relationship.

Comment: Ask a question on how you'd do that avoiding the circular references I'll be happy to attempt an answer. Seeing as I don't now all your criteria for the model, I can't for certain, but personally I'd go a looooong way out of my way to avoid the crack you are in now.

Comment: The solution would be easy, remove make the id nullable, and all works perfectly. But then it's an error if the field is NULL. So it'd still have to be in a transaction that rollbacks on error.

Comment: Hardly a solution is it then? Address_user with unique key on Userid was my first thought....

Comment: I don't see the use in that at all, then you can just as well have one address column. (Btw. adres = the dutch word for address.) The thing is, every person can have an undetermined amount of addresses, but *has* to have one main address. One of the things obviously would be to add a flag that states if it's the main address, but I don't like that. It seems better to simply store the main address in the user table.

Comment: Addresses (ID(PK), Address). Users(UserID(PK) AddressID(FK)). UserAddresses(UserID (FK), AddressID (FK), Unique(UserId, AddressID). It's hard doing this blind, but like I said, I'd be trying hard to avoid where you've ended up.

Comment: That's many to many. While it should be 1 (user) to many (addresses). So there's no use in it, but if there's no way to insert two at the same time, then I guess making it nullable is the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get rid of disabling of foreign key checks is by making `U_Main_Adres` nullable.